# Probability of guessing a list

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is "A history quiz has one question where the students are asked to arranged the first ten presidents in correct chronological order. If a student is totally unprepared and makes a random list, what is the probability of getting the incorrect order? The correct order?"

I tried to just do 10! (10 factorial) and got 3,628,800

So I figured probability of guessing correctly is 1/3,628,800 = 2.76 E^-7
And incorrectly is 3,628,799/3,628,800 = .9999997244

Did I do this correctly or is this wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Everything correct!

Comment: Thanks bud :) Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer looks correct.

You could extend this to find the probability a student ordering at random got $n$ out of $10$ correct.  The following table shows the number of ways, known as [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) and (after dividing by $10!=3628800$) the approximate probabilities.

```
correct ways    probability
0       1334961 0.3678794643
1       1334960 0.3678791887
2        667485 0.1839409722
3        222480 0.0613095238
4         55650 0.0153356481
5         11088 0.0030555556
6          1890 0.0005208333
7           240 0.0000661376
8            45 0.0000124008
9             0 0.0000000000
10            1 0.0000002756
```

The expected number is $1$.

Comment: Thank ya very much Henry! :D